# JMeter: What is the Best Assertion Type to Validate a Single Node Value in an XML?

Tags: xml, validation, jmeter

I've been reading a lot of discussion and posts on Assertions, including:

- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)
- [JMeter Response Assertion Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-jmeter/jmeter-response-assertion-example/)
- [What is the valid XPATH to validate the node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034829/what-is-the-valid-xpath-to-validate-the-node)

I am still unclear as to the most efficient way to validate a particular node value an XML response.

I have an HTTP Request Sampler where I pass in a JSON payload to a MS SQL Server database where the database performs a calculation and returns back an XML response.

The only thing I want to validate is  `<calculationSuccessfulIndicator>true</calculationSuccessfulIndicator>`

It's pretty much a binary test. It's either true (pass) or false (fail). And I have a positive test data and a negative test data to ensure it fails when it should and passes when it should. (no need to validate the xsd or anything other part of the xml)

To me, the XPath Assertion seemed like the most accurate way to achieve this. I set it to Apply to Main sample and sub-samples and defined the XPath Assertion to be `/Response/PricingUnit/PrimaryAllocation/PricingTerm/calculationSuccessfulIndicator`
But how do I specify the node value of "true"?

Next, I tried a Response Assertion where I set it to check The only thing I want to validate is  `<calculationSuccessfulIndicator>true</calculationSuccessfulIndicator>`. Problem with is was, even when the actual value was "false", the assertion still passed.

I continued on with trying performing a RegEx on the response and then passed that into a Compare Assertion; but it always passed, even on the negative test.

Anyone have any thoughts on what would be the most efficient and the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't read referenced articles either at all or attentive enough, the first link states:

> To give an idea as to how it should work, here are a few assertions on the example.com domain:
>
> `//title/text()='Example Domain'`- checks  tag text to be “Example Domain” - will **PASS**

Assuming above statement you need the following XPath Expression in the XPath Assertion:

```
/Response/PricingUnit/PrimaryAllocation/PricingTerm/calculationSuccessfulIndicator/text()='true'
```

I do not guarantee that it will work until I see your full XML response, however it should give you an idea regarding how to proceed.

By the way, it is possible to test XPath Expressions against live response right in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener using "XPath Tester" mode. Here is an example demonstrating that above XPath query works fine:

[image: XPath Tester]

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details on getting to the bottom of your JMeter test problem.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I did read each link, but I was not able to translate `//title/text()='Example Domain'- checks <title> tag text to be “Example Domain” - will PASS`  into  `/Response/PricingUnit/PrimaryAllocation/PricingTerm/calculationSuccessfulIndicator/text()='true'` Now that I see them side by side, it makes sense. I guess my lack of programming knowledge was my downfall.

Comment: XPath is easy, I believe if you spend several minutes reading http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp you'll know it better than I do